Adjusting the indentation and the horizontal spacing in tables in latex
I'm trying to make a partial list of symbols in my thesis. So far, I have written this code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in,headsep=22pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{A Partial List of Symbols} 
\begin{tabular}{l l}
 $+$ & Addition Operator\\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

But unfortunately this is not precisely what I need. I need to make a bigger distance between the two columns (e.g., make a larger distance between $+$ and its description 'Addition Operator'). I tried adding \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3em} before \begin{tabular}{l l}. This seems to be a solution of the problem but, unfortunately, the whole table moves to the right whenever the distance (3em or whatever) increases. I need to keep the indentation of whole table so that the indentation of the table agrees with the indentation of the title of the chapter.
I also need to keep the two columns left aligned.
Can this be fixed? I need any help. Also I will be grateful if one can give me the easiest and shortest solution for this problem.

Try using the tabularray package, which will give you a lot more control over how your tables are laid out.

Try something like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in,headsep=22pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{A Partial List of Symbols} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{3em}} l}
 $+$ & Addition Operator\\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Output:

Explanation:
First @{} is used to eliminate the initial column separation so that you will get the desired align with the chapter title.
The second @{} contains the extra skip appropriate command (\extracolsep{3em}). Keep in mind it will affect following possible columns too.
EDIT:
Solution with pagebreaks (supertabular):
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in,headsep=22pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{A Partial List of Symbols}

\begin{supertabular}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{3em}} l}
 $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
  $+$ & Addition Operator \\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}


This is a good answer. Why the table does not break into two pages (or more) if it does not fit one page?

You need to use longtable or supertabular  or other similar solutions for this. tabular is not breakable (automatically by default).

Ok. I tried to replace tabular by longtable but this broke the indentation!!!!

@HusseinEid ... See edit with supertabular that is easier. longtable needs some more changes (is actually somehow easy but has its own rules -not needed in your case I suppose-)

Thank you for your help :)

Welcome @HusseinEid ... Happy TeXing!

Assuming that the descriptions don't need to be broken across lines, you can use a tabular when the list fits a single page or longtable otherwise.
Instead of @{\quad} you can use @{\hspace{<length>}} with the length you prefer.
Table fits in one page
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in,headsep=22pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A Partial List of Symbols}

\noindent% for safety
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\qquad} l @{}}
 $+$ & Addition Operator\\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Table needs more than one page
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in,headsep=22pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A Partial List of Symbols}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l @{\qquad} l @{}}
 $+$ & Addition Operator\\
 $-$ & Subtraction Operator\\
 $\times$ & Multiplication Operator\\
 $\sqrt{x}$ & Square Root of $x$\\
 $\odot$ & Foo Bar\\
 $\mathbb{Z}_n (n>1)$ & Bar Foo
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}

Output


Thanks @egreg. This is also a nice solution.
